# Creating two different instances on one Sitecore Commerce Server

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is it possible to have various Sitecore instances/versions with the same installed Commerce Server?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be done.

Below things need to take care:

1. Change commerce databases (Shared and global) name
2. Change commerce related indexes name (Commerce, catalog and customer)
3. Change default port used for commerce roles

For more details please have a look below blog:

https://vipinbankablog.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/install-multiple-sitecore-commerce-instances-on-single-machine/

Hoping this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Each `Sitecore Commerce` version must be compatible with `Sitecore` version based on Sitecore Commerce compatibility tables:

- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/316437 - shows the Sitecore CMS/XP 8.2 and older versions compatibility with different versions of Sitecore Commerce and Sitecore Commerce Connect.
- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595 - for Sitecore XP 9.0 and Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 releases compatibility information.